# Смена User-Agent с помощью QWebEngineProfile на QWebEngineView. Как правильно?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Делаю такую подстановку кода

```py
       self.useragent = QWebEngineProfile(self.browser)
       self.useragent.setHttpUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36')
```

Однако юзер агент не меняет.

Вот более больший кусок кода:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        page = WebEnginePage(self.browser)
        self.useragent = QWebEngineProfile(self.browser)
        self.useragent.setHttpUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36')

        self.browser.setPage(page)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://whoer.net/"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
```

Что я делаю не правильно по привязки к QWebEngineView - QWebEngineProfile? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такой код:

```
self.useragent = QWebEngineProfile(self.browser)
self.useragent.defaultProfile().setHttpUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36')
```